# How to retrieve username of Facebook user in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

What is the procedure to retrieve the user name of Facebook user when try to login our bot from Facebook channel?

Let share us any document or procedure to get the user name of Facebook login user to our bot.

Comment: IMRANKHAN K  check this    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964566/access-facebook-messenger-user-profile-api-in-dialogflow