# Get Facebook user details when user interacts with chatbot

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialogflow-es

I'm new to Dialogflow and I wanted to integrate it to Facebook Messenger using webhooks. Problem is that I don't know how GRAPH API works. I already created my chatbot and tested it on the console. It works like this:

```
User: book appointment
Bot: Ask for credentials (username, password, etc.)
```

After validation it then saves it to my database. The problem with this is that the chatbot will ask the user password when asking an update for appointment status.

I wanted to integrate to Facebook Messenger because the chatbot won't be constantly asking for the user password as it will use the `FB:ID` to verify the user account.

Any idea how to translate it to code? I'm using nodejs to write my code?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to use the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964566/access-facebook-messenger-user-profile-api-in-dialogflow) ? There is a description on how to get it via graph api.

Comment: @ewertonvsilva sorry for the really late reply. I've checked it and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Post an answer as community wiki, as this solution has solved the issue. The solution based on Graph Api posted on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51964566):

---

You need to make a call to [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/) in order to get user's profile.

Facebook offers some SDKs for this, but their official JavaScript SDK is more intended to be on a web client, not on a server.  They mention some 3rd party Node.js libraries on that link. I'm particularly using [`fbgraph`](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph) (at the time of writing, it's the only one that seems to be "kind of" maintained).

So, you need a Page Token to make the calls. While developing, you can get one from here:
`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<your app id>/messenger/settings/`

Here's some example code:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util');
let graph = require('fbgraph'); // facebook graph library

const fbGraph = {
  get: promisify(graph.get)
}

graph.setAccessToken(FACEBOOK_PAGE_TOKEN);  // <--- your facebook page token
graph.setVersion("3.2");

// gets profile from facebook
// user must have initiated contact for sender id to be available
// returns: facebook profile object, if any
async function getFacebookProfile(agent) {
  let ctx = agent.context.get('generic');
  let fbSenderID = ctx ? ctx.parameters.facebook_sender_id : undefined;
  let payload;

  console.log('FACEBOOK SENDER ID: ' + fbSenderID);

  if ( fbSenderID ) {
    try { payload = await fbGraph.get(fbSenderID) }
    catch (err) { console.warn( err ) }
  }

  return payload;
}
```

Notice you don't always have access to the sender id, and in case you do, you don't always have access to the profile. For some fields like `email`, you need to request special permissions. Regular fields like name and profile picture are usually available if the user is the one who initiates the conversation. More info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile#availability).

**Edit**

Promise instead of async:

```js
function getFacebookProfile(agent) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let ctx = agent.context.get('generic');
    let fbSenderID = ctx ? ctx.parameters.facebook_sender_id : undefined;

    console.log('FACEBOOK SENDER ID: ' + fbSenderID);

    fbGraph.get( fbSenderID )
      .then( payload => {
        console.log('all fine: ' + payload);
        resolve( payload );
      })
      .catch( err => {
        console.warn( err );
        reject( err );
      });
  });
}
```